# When will g++ not need -std=c++0x

Tags: c++, g++, c++11

Is there someone on the list "in the know" that can tell us when c++11 features in g++ will no longer be "experimental"? That is, when will "-std=c++0x" not be necessary to get current standard (C++11)? (Presumably, that would also speak to how confident that community is in the supported features.)
I am similarly interested in Clang.

Comment: Clang and GCC are both Open Source projects. This means that, generally, they don't have "schedules". They don't have an idea of when something might happen. They will be non-experimental when they are, and not before then. Also, C++11 is not 100% backwards compatible with C++03, so you will always need to have some command line to differentiate the two.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the only back-wards compatibility issue would be with the "auto" keyword. I've never seen auto used in production code (old-style auto, that is), so I doubt this would be a problem.

Comment: At the end of the spec, there is a big list of things in C++11 that are not backwards compatible with C++03. Aggregate initialization narrowing, for example (`int x[] = {2.0};` will fail in C++11). New keywords is another example (I hope you didn't use `decltype` in your C++ code). Even integer division changed to always round towards zero (where before it rounded down, always) can be breaking. `std::swap` was moved to a different header. I can keep going, but I think my point is clear: you can't just force people to compile C++03 as C++11, if you're being conformant with the spec.

Comment: @Nicol Your first comment betrays a misunderstanding of Open Source. Why should Open Source projects not have a (tightly regulates!) schedule? I do know certain OSS projects that have *very* tightly regulates schedules that project far in advance (Firefox and Ubuntu, just to name two). I don’t think that there is necessarily any correlation between OSS and “has a schedule”.

Comment: If it bothers you, just branch GCC and change the way it handles .cpp/.cc files by default.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Can you give me the reference for integer divide? 5.6 still indicates truncation in my copy of the draft standard.

Comment: This question would be better suited on GCC and CLANG's respective forums or mailing lists.

Comment: @John: I'm just going by what the standard says in the section at the end. Section C.2.2, in N3291. I don't have the C++03 standard to compare it to.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: You're a lot less likely to find schedule-driven coding among volunteers. When it happens, it's usually because they are *hired* programmers (Firefox and Ubuntu have a paid staff).

Comment: @Mat, mailing lists suck.  Forums suck, but less. Stackexchange has to be the best way I've see in a long time to share information.  I'm interested to know John answer but I don't know that I'll ever find it if it gets asked on a mailing list.  Even if it is answered and i find it how do I know if that was the best/right one?  Keep reading?  Get to know the everyone on the list so I can judge their credibility?  I'm really tired of the "please use the mailing list" comments.  Now it may be the case that SO is not site to handle this question, but that's a different topic.

Comment: @deft_code: it's not really appropriate for SO - it asks for speculation (unless that info has been published by the GCC and CLANG teams), and having to specify `-std=c++0x` (or `-std=c99` for that matter) isn't a real practical problem: all (usable) build systems have ways of specifying compiler flags. (And some would argue that explicitly specifying the standard you're coding against is a good thing, too).

Comment: whenever you think you don't need it just add an alias in your .bashrc